# Install node.js modules in eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, socket.io, node-modules

I am trying to develop a chat app with node.js and socket.io in an eclipse environment.  I have installed node.js in eclipse but I don't know how to install node modules such as expresss, socket io, etc.

Please anyone tell me how to setup node modules in an eclipse environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think that  there is an eclipse integrated way to do this. My suggestion is that you download node.js+npm from http://nodejs.org/download/ and then open up a terminal/cmd and in your node.js project directory do "npm install myPackage"

Comment: Thanks for u response. But am implementing this project in eclispe IDE.So obviously i have to integrate nodejs with eclispe right..

Comment: well you could handle the packages from outside eclipse and still implement and run it from within eclipse with the node plugin.

Comment: Did u find answer how to integrate  express or any other node js module in eclipse like a jar or something. I installed express using npm command but my eclipse is not taking that.

Answer (score 7):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodeclipse/FgUci2ZXpoQ

1. Double-click package.json on the Package Explorer to open it.
2. Add into dependencies section what you want to install, and save it.
3. Select package.json on  the Package Explorer, open context menu by right-clicking, and select [Run As]-[npm install] menu.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Eclipse Mars...  Here is how I did it...

1. Install Nodeclipse from eclipse marketplace http://www.nodeclipse.org/
2. Create a new node.js express project, File -> New Node.Js Express Project
3. Open the package.json file
4. Add my npm package to the package.json as a dependency (copy the format for the express dependency)
5. **Save the package.json**  (seems obvious but it got me when testing!)
6. Right click the package.json, Run As -> NPM Install
7. Right click the eclipse project folder, Refresh
8. Open node_modules... BOOM!  You will see your new module installed in eclipse

Comment: Please share example about package.json

Answer (score 2):

You mention installing express, but you don't need to install that if you're using nodeclipse.

to generate an express project:
Select the File-New-Project menu.
Select Node-Express Project, and select Next button.
Enter Project name and select Finish button.

Answer (score 2):

To install express modules in Nodeclipse go to

**Windows -> Preferences-> Nodeclipse -> choose express path field**

and enter the location of the installed express on your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your project folder via command prompt. Once there, run the npm install 'module' command. After the module installs, refresh your project in eclipse. A javascript library should show up in your project containing the library of the module you just installed. Run your code and it should work and recognize the modules that your are trying to require. 
Hope this helps.