# How to install socket.io plugin of nodejs in ecllipse?

Tags: java, node.js

```
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on('set nickname', function (name) {
 socket.set('nickname', name, function () {
 socket.emit('ready');
});
});

socket.on('msg', function () {
socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
  console.log('Chat message by ', name);
});
});
});
```

While running this code i am getting an Error:

> Cannot find module 'socket.io'.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no eclipse integration available for Node.js and its dependencies or modules. you need to download the rpm or deb build and install it on your system.

Refer: [Install node.js modules in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446866/install-node-js-modules-in-eclipse)